# Handing transaction in Spring with third party code

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am getting transaction issues with third party code.

In Service layer i am doing two database insert

1. With my own code
2. With third party code (call goes to service layer of the third party code)

I am explaining the code like below

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class InvoiceserviceImpl implements Invoiceservice{

    @Override
    public void processinvoice() {
        // 1. Data base inserting logic via DAO Layer

        // 2. Data base insertion logic via another service (code is third party in the form of JAR) 

        // 3. some more logic
    }
}
```

As you can see class is Transactional.

**processinvoice** method has three layers, database insert in own code, database insert with third party code and the last one some more logic.

Now the problem which i am facing is that if any exception happens in third section, rollback is happening for DB call No 1, but not for DB call no 2 (which is third party code)

Comment: What's the "third party code" transaction propagation policy? You'll see stuff like that if that code creates its own separate transaction.

Comment: Indeed, if the 3rd party code has no idea about Spring's transaction context, it's not going to be able to join an existing transaction.

Comment: @Kayaman, it could, if you could tell it that it should use `Propagation.REQUIRES` instead of `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`, for example. There are couple of policy values that support continuing existing transactions.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Not for code that doesn't know anything about Spring's transaction context, i.e. if the 3rd party code is not "spring aware". Calling non-managed code inside a method that's annotated with `@Transactional` does not make the non-managed code transactional.

Comment: Not Propagation rules are mentioned in the third party code, so it will take default REQUIRES

Comment: Without knowning how the third-party code is doing database access and/or managing transaction there is no answer that will help you get to a solution.

Comment: my code is calling the service layer of the third party code, and i am sure that Service layer is not Transnational